# get link from jquery object

Tags: jquery, html

I know this is probably very easy to do, but let's say I have something like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.my_link', function(){

       var my_anchor_object = $(this)     

 });
```

How do I get the actual anchor string:

```
<a href="test.com" id="my_link_id" class="my_link_class">My Link</a>
```

Of my link (not the jQuery object) from `my_anchor_object`?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want the link ( href ) or just the hash (#) section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like

```
var my_anchor_object = $(this).attr('href');
```

and you can use this **href** for your anchor tag.If you want an entire tag try like

```
var my_anchor_ref = $(this).attr('href');
var my_anchor_txt = $(this).text();   
//Now append to a div
$('#my_div_id').append('<a href="'+my_anchor_ref+'">'+my_anchor_txt+'</a>');
```

Haha simply try with

```
var my_anchor = $(this).get(0);
$('#my_div_id').append(my_anchor);
```

Comment: Isn't this gonna give me just the value of the `href` attribute of my anchor? I don't want just the value of `href`

Comment: I want my anchor `<a href="test.com">My Link</a>`

Comment: What if my anchor can contain some other attributes like `id` `class` and possibly some other dynamically added attributes

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.my_link', function(){
   var my_anchor_object = $(this).clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
    alert(my_anchor_object);
});
```

check at http://jsfiddle.net/Pyk4Y/25/

Comment: Isn`t the parent of the anchor supposed to be the html document in this case?

Comment: You dont need to put any parent or put it. Doesn't matter. It will give you the right solution in any case.